# Show only 7 list items in list, on "next" click hide current 7 show next 7, same with "previous" click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I have a long list

```
<a class="prev">prev</a>
<a class="next">next</a>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, show only the first 3 list item, if click on "next" HIDE current 3 and show next 3, and so on.... the same with previous, if clicked HIDE current 3 and show previous 3...

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/tfa0Lyem

It seems to work, but I can't workaround how to HIDE the current shown items..

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to show and hide your li - see comments in code below

```js
var current = 0,
  numToShow = 3,
  $li = $('#myList').children();          // get all li once and work with this set for better performance

function showLi() {
  var startIndex = current * numToShow;   // calculate your slice start number
  if (startIndex > $li.length) {          // if start number greater than number of li, reset
    startIndex = 0;
    current = 0;
  } else if (current < 0) {               // if start number less than 0, reset to end
    current = Math.floor($li.length / numToShow);
    startIndex = current * numToShow;
  }

  $li.hide()                                   // hide all li
    .slice(startIndex, startIndex + numToShow) // slice off the ones you want to show
    .show();                                   // show them
}

showLi();

$('#next').click(function() {
  current++; // increment current
  showLi();
})

$('#prev').click(function() {
  current--; // decrement current
  showLi();
})
```

```css
#myList li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
</ul>

<a id="prev">prev</a>
<a id="next">next</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = jQuery("#myList li").size();
    x = 3;
    y = 0;
    jQuery('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    jQuery('#next').click(function () {
        x = (x+3 <= size_li) ? x+3 : size_li;
        y= x-3
        jQuery('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
         jQuery('#myList li:lt('+y+')').hide();
    });
    jQuery('#prev').click(function () {
        jQuery('#myList li:lt('+x+')').hide()
        x = (x-3<0) ? 0 : x-3;
        y = (x - 3 <= 0 ) ? 0 : x - 3 ;
        jQuery('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
        jQuery('#myList li:lt('+y+')').hide()
       }); 
});
```

```css
#myList li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>      
    </ul>
    
<a id="prev">prev</a>
<a id="next">next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work ( I didn't test it, but the structure should be something like it)

```
var liSize = $("li").length();
    var change = 3;  // Elements you want to show or hide
    var Last = change-1;   // Keep the posicion of the last <li> visible elemente
    $("#next").click(function(){
        $("li").css("display","none");  // Hide all <li> elements
        for(var i=0; i<change; i++){   // repeat 3 times, or depending on change variable
            if(Last<liSize){   // Stop after the last existing element
                Last++;    // change the position to the next element
                $("lit:nth-child("+Last+")").css("display","block");   // Show the next element 
            }
        }
    });
    $("#previous").click(function(){
        Last-= change;          // Obtain the first visible elemente
        $("li").css("display","none");   // Hide all elements
        for(var i=0; i<change; i++){
            if(Last>=0){   // stop after the first element changes
                $("li:nth-child("+Last+")").css("display","block");
                Last-1;    
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you also tagged javascript and all answers are in jQuery I present to you a vanilla solution. It's intentionally more verbose than needed so that the example is easy to follow.

Everything is contained in a mutable object so that you can easily change the list size and the current index. This way you can also dynamically change the list and the target (where to list the items)

I know you are writing in jQuery, but someone might find it useful.

```js
const list = {
  target: document.getElementById("myUl"),
  fullList: document.getElementById("myUl").querySelectorAll(".myLi"),
  itemsToList: 7,
  index: 0,
  // remove all children, append the amout of items we want
  update: function() {
    while (this.target.firstChild) {
      this.target.removeChild(this.target.firstChild);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.itemsToList; i += 1) {
      if(this.fullList[this.index + i]) {
        this.target.appendChild(this.fullList[this.index + i]);
      }
    }
  },
  prev: function() {
    // if index 1 is displayed, go to end of list
    if (this.index <= 0) { 
      this.index = this.fullList.length; 
    }
    // decrement the index
    this.index -= this.itemsToList;
    // lower edge case, catch to always list the same amout of items
    if (this.index < 0) { 
      this.index = 0; 
    }
  },
  next: function() {
    // increment the index
    this.index += this.itemsToList;
    // if last item is shown start from beginning
    if (this.index >= this.fullList.length) {
      this.index = 0;
    } 
    // catch upper edge case, always list the same amout of items
    else if ( this.index > this.fullList.length - this.itemsToList + 1) {
      this.index = this.fullList.length - this.itemsToList;
    }
  }
}
// initialize by removing list and showing from index[0]
list.update();

document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener('click', function () {
  list.prev();
  list.update();
});

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener('click', function () {
  list.next();
  list.update();
});
```

```html
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
  <ul id="myUl">
  <li class="myLi">item 1</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 2</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 3</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 4</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 5</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 6</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 7</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 8</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 9</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 10</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 11</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 12</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 13</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 14</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 15</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 16</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 17</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 18</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 19</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 20</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 21</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 22</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 23</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 24</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 25</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 26</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 27</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 28</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 29</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 30</li>
  <li class="myLi">item 31</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var size_li = jQuery("#myList li").size();
    // visible list length, if you want show 7 ,change it
    var step = 3;
    // first visible list 
    var cache = 3;
    jQuery('#myList li:lt('+cache+')').show();

    jQuery('#next').click(function () {
        cache = (cache+step <= size_li) ? cache+step : size_li;
        jQuery('#myList li:lt('+cache+')').show();
        jQuery('#myList li:lt('+(cache-step)+')').hide();
        //  
    });
    jQuery('#prev').click(function () {
        cache = (cache-step<step) ? step : cache-step;
        console.log(cache)
        jQuery('#myList li:lt('+(cache)+')').show();
        jQuery('#myList li:lt('+(cache-step)+')').hide();
        jQuery('#myList li:gt('+(cache-1)+')').hide();

    });
});
```

Comment: You should explain what they were doing wrong and how you fixed it.